# How can I delete the group from my iphone simulator?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm adding contact details to the address book from my app. And I have many groups with the same name. How can I delete the groups from my simulator, manually or programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the main menu of the iPhone Simulator, you can click on "Reset content and settings" and this will give you a fresh simulator to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3(Your base SDK)/Applications
and delete your app...